# Multiple row and column layout in android

Tags: android

I want to create the following layout in Android.

[image]

What's the best layout to achieve this UI in multiple screen size? I've tried to use LinearLayout and set the layout_weight, however the second row will require another layout_weight and it's bad for performance. I've tried to use TableLayout as well but the third row is not seen due to large image size.

Should I use LinearLayout and create the images for each screen size (mdpi, hdpi, etc)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try out relative layout

Comment: as I can see best way is Linear layout with weight.
safe and secure and less complex. or else u will hav lot of hard work and risks. in multiple support screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is your required lyout. Using weight is not a performance issue unless used wisely. Performance issue occurs only if you are using too much of nested layouts with weight. Whenever we are developing Screens Supporting Multiple resolutions weight is the best thing around.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/img_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to prepare the images with predefined width and height for each screen size? I imagine if the image used is a large one, it will occupy most of the screen.

Comment: Yes you must have a set of images in your HDPI,MDPI and XHDPI folder for each screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. This is a waighted layout design work with all screens.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OutpUt**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here's a outline of the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/abox"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lin_lt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_1">
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/abox"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/abox"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lin_lt"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/abox"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can get rid of the LinearLayout if you provide appropriately sized images for each of the screen size/density group. And its always a better idea to use appropriately sized images for each screen size/density or use 9patch images.

Comment: this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) suggests that you should always try to use RelativeLayout wherever possible to make things fullproof for all screens size/density and should provide drawable resources for major screen size/density groups.